# How do I set up a embedded MySQL server in Qt

Tags: mysql, qt, embedded-database, libmysql, qsqldatabase

I tried this code from the MySQL reference but it crashes when it comes to the point `mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP, "libmysqld_client");`. Does somebody has a working exmaple for a embedded server?

```
#include <mysql.h>

static char *server_options[] = {"mysql_test", "--defaults-file=my.ini", NULL};
int num_elements = (sizeof(server_options) / sizeof(char *)) - 1;
static char *server_groups[] = {"libmysqld_server", "libmysqld_client", NULL};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QSqlDatabase mydb;
    MYSQL *mysql;

    mysql_library_init(num_elements, server_options, server_groups);
    mysql = mysql_init(NULL);
    mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP, "libmysqld_client");
    mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_OPT_USE_EMBEDDED_CONNECTION, NULL);

    mysql_real_connect(mysql, NULL, NULL, NULL, "database1", 0, NULL, 0);

    mydb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "con1");

    mydb.setDatabaseName("database1");

    if(!mydb.open())
    {
        qDebug() << mydb.lastError();
    }

    mysql_library_end();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this line of code before `mysql_real_connect()`.

```
mysql_init(mysql);
mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP,"your program name");
```